# DB Insertion Issue on Materialized View in PSQL

Tags: view, psql

I have been working on creating the trigger for one materialized view like this in PSQL using supruser:

```
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    refresh materialized view mat_view;
    return null;
end $$;

create trigger refresh_mat_view
after insert or update or delete or truncate
on table1 for each statement 
execute procedure refresh_mat_view();

create trigger refresh_mat_view
after insert or update or delete or truncate
on table2 for each statement 
execute procedure refresh_mat_view();
```

After set up the trigger, when others tried to insert records in table1, it showed failed to insert and must be the owner of the mat_view. Is there any way that I can get around this for creating the trigger and also allow others to insert?

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.rustprooflabs.com/2021/07/postgres-permission-mat-view
Issue can be solved here by creating a group of role to be act as an owner or using a cron job